# jquery checked and unchecked events

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a problem here with the following code

```
$('.paron').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          var moduleid = <?php echo $moduleid; ?>;
                var studentid = $(this).attr('id');
                var weeknum = <?php echo $weeknum; ?>;

                undisableTxt(studentid);

             }
       });
```

So I take the `id` of a certain `tr` which has an `input` and i send it to a function. All good till now.
But this is happening when the user `check` the `input [checkbox]`
when he UNCHECK, how can i have the `id` to send it to another function???

I've tried the following but no luck

```
   $('.paron').change(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     var moduleid = <?php echo $moduleid; ?>;
     var studentid = $(this).attr('id');
     var weeknum = <?php echo $weeknum; ?>;

             undisableTxt(studentid);

      } else {
        disableTxt(studentid); //error for undefined variable student id.
      }
  });
```

So i get an error for undefined `studentid`. FYI each row has another id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'studentId' doesn't exist in your else block. Also you shouldn't define variables with var in blocks, because var doesn't scope variables at the block level, use let or const for that. I also set $this, to save going back and forth into the DOM for performance.

in jQuery you would do it like this.

```
$('.paron').change(function() {
  const $this = $(this);  
  const studentid = $this.attr('id');

  if($this.is(":checked")) {
    // removed for brevity, but using let or const
    undisableTxt(studentid);
  } else {
    disableTxt(studentid); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I also found out another workaround with `closest` but yours its better! Thanks a lot!! gonna accept it when system let me to!

Comment: Thanks, hopefully, my other comments/changes don't seem rude or know-it-all, I just wanted to make the example best as I could.

Comment: I'm newbie to jquery and this about `const` and `let` helps me a lot cause i've seen `let` only in swift and i know it has great performance !! much appreciated :D